# C#: Pass filters to ADLS gen2 storage from C# and get the result

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-databricks

I am working on angular application which consumes data from azure data lake (gen2) and bind it to UI.

My requirement is to pass filters to gen2 storage and get the filtered data.

> I don't want to download whole blob file and then do processing in C#.

is it possible to pass filters/query to gen2 blob storage and filter data in storage it self ?

Comment: the blob like xml?

Comment: json files.( FIles are created using databricks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which SDK or api you're using, but both of [ADLS Gen2 read api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/read) and [blob storage read api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) don't support filter feature.

You should always download the file to local first, then fetch the data you need; Or you can use blob storage sdk(partially supports ADLS Gen2) to read the json file in memory, then fetch the needed data.